# Why Will This HTML Not Print?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure why, but the HTML that is supposed to print when the screen width is below 1230 pixels will not display.  Looking for some advice as to why.  Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width < 1230) {
           document.write('
           <ul class="navbar-holder">
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem-active"><a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>">home</a></li>
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">our services</a></li>
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">our work</a></li>
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
            ');
        }
        else {
            document.write('
            <select class="mobile-page-selector">
                <option>Home</option>
            </select>
            ');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: There are much better ways to do what you are trying to do. Look at `bootstrap framework`. You will have a class that only displays for widths less then 1230 etc. CSS is the way - `@media screen and (max-width: 1230px)`.

Comment: The problem is with the tags. http://jsfiddle.net/XhNNz/

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript strings can’t contain newlines; you can escape them with a backslash at the end of each line, or concatenate several strings.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width < 1230) {
           document.write('\
           <ul class="navbar-holder">\
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem-active"><a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>">home</a></li>\
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">about us</a></li>\
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">our services</a></li>\
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">our work</a></li>\
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">blog</a></li>\
                <li id="navitem" class="navbaritem"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>\
            </ul>\
            ');
        }
        else {
            document.write('\
            <select class="mobile-page-selector">\
                <option>Home</option>\
            </select>\
            ');
        }
</script>
```

May I recommend CSS instead? This JavaScript only applies once, and generating HTML in JavaScript is usually *wrong*. If you use a media query:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1230px) {
    .navbar-holder {
        /* Apply some `display: none`s, perhaps */
    }
}
```

it will be more efficient, easier to use, accessible without JavaScript, and responsive to window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your enters with backslashes:

```
document.write("a\
b");
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side, JavaScript won't be able to `document.write` any PHP and have it execute

That said, JavaScript thinks you have a syntax error at

`href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>`

due to the `'` ending the initial string

Comment: PHP doesn’t recognize script blocks, either; I’d assume the PHP code is processed.

Comment: @minty Yes, it should be. I wonder if there's a way to escape PHP in a JavaScript block.